# Selenium - How to debug code in driver.ExecuteScript String

Tags: html, image, selenium, canvas, download

In my vb.net Project with `Selenium`, I have a set of `JS` statements to convert html to `canvas` to `image` and then `download` to file. The code so far is as follows:-

```
driver.ExecuteScript("
                        var url = '" + str + "';
                        var pages = [],
                          heights = [],
                          width = 0,
                          height = 0,
                          currentPage = 1;
                        var scale = 1.5;

                        PDFJS.disableWorker = true; // due to CORS
                        PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function(pdf) {
                          pdf.getPage(currentPage).then(function(page) {
                            console.log('Printing ' + currentPage);
                            var viewport = page.getViewport({
                              scale: scale,
                            });
                            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                              ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                            var renderContext = {
                              canvasContext: ctx,
                              viewport: viewport
                            };
                            canvas.height = viewport.height;
                            canvas.width = viewport.width;
                            page.render(renderContext).then(function() {
                              pages.push(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
                              heights.push(height);
                              height += canvas.height;
                              if (width < canvas.width) width = canvas.width;

                              var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                                ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                              canvas.width = width;
                              canvas.height = height;
                              for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++)
                                ctx.putImageData(pages[i], 0, heights[i]);
                              document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                              var element = document.createElement('a');
                              element.setAttribute('href', document.getElementById('rakCanvas').toDataURL('image/png'));
                              element.setAttribute('download', '" + fileName + "');
                              console.log('Raky ========>' + url);
                              element.style.display = 'block';
                              document.body.appendChild(element);
                              element.click();
                              //document.body.removeChild(element);
                              return 'Done Rak';
                            });
                          });

                        });
```

Using `jsfiddle`, I found the `JS` code to be without any syntax errors. There are no errors during compiling and execution. And there is no file downloaded. To figure out the problem, I am looking for a way to monitor execution of each statement of above js code.

Alternatively, if there is a code chuck that could help in just converting the HTML canvas to Image to be downloaded as a file.

Comment: Selenium isn't really meant to execute long pieces of scripts like this... I mean, it CAN, it's just not advised, because you can't debug this kind of thing with just Selenium. You might need to search for a JS debugger outside of `Driver.ExecuteScript`, because that's not something Selenium can help you debug.

Comment: Yes, I did realise this.